# How to get Py4Delphi to use a Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, delphi

I am using Delphi 10.4 to invoke a python script using the Py4Delphi library.

How can I execute the script with respect to a particular python virtual environment directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the virtual environment is basically setting a few environment variables before running python. You can look into scripts\activate.bat which variables that are.

You don't need to recover those changes after running it, because within a process you're running with a copy of the system environment.

Comment: Thanks. To add further detail, the steps are: (1) Set the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable to the venv directory plus a trailing forward slash; (2) Clear the PYTHONHOME environment variable; (3) Prepend the PATH environment variable with the venv directory (prolly not necessary); and (4) Set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to any additional paths that you would like to load.

---

These envars must be set before p4d dll load.